# How can i set my credentials for `aws` in boto?

Tags: python, github-api, amazon-lex

Trying to run my chatbot on LEX engine from python according to this link https://github.com/boto/boto3#quick-start .

Being a starter in Github and amazon Lex i don't understand how to set these up :

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = YOUR_KEY
aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_SECRET
```

It says to create this in `~/.aws/credentials` but I'm not sure what that means.

I have already set the virtual environment and ran `pip install boto3` again my question is how to set that step i mentioned above and where.

Comment: The first or second hit when googling `aws_access_key_id` solves this. The AWS docs state you got the secret key when you created an access `key`, and if you didn't yet there's a link to create one.

Comment: You didn't understand my question, my issue is where to input these values, in python, in some repository, in the cmd...

Comment: Well i didn't understand where that kindly put in answer in a more clear way for a beginner if you can, thanks.

Comment: i have ran mkdir ~/.aws then readlink -f file.txt to find my path, i went there and didn't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `C:\Users\user_name` there you will find a folder `.aws`. Put your credentials and config files inside that folder.

Comment: On LInux, can you adjust accordingly(this answer is for windows)

Comment: on Linux go to your home directory there you should find .aws folder

Comment: http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/the-linux-file-system-structure-explained this might be useful

Comment: i see it now, do i put them in a text file or python file

Comment: filename will be **credentials** without any extensions. mark the answer as accepted if it helped.